# Storing medical ailments in a database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to find the best method to store medical ailments , like Diabetes, Hypertension, Cancer etc in a 
database.

My form will list over 200 ailments and the user will check those that affect him. I could serialize those
selected and then store it in a database but I want to be able to use the information at a later stage.
For example I want to know what ailments are selected with Diabetes and Hypertension.
Does this mean I will have to create a field for each ailment in my database ?

I am confused here.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks
Kimmy

Answer (score 1):

No need to serialize. A relational database (such as MySQL) is intended to store one fact per row. This is the proper way to do it.

Have an `Ailments` table. It will have 200 rows - one per ailment. This will be used to populate the user's check list.

On save, write each checked ailment to a `UserAilment` table. It will consist of a foreign key to the user table and a foreign key to `Ailments`.

Comment: If this is a paper form and not used on a computer screen, then there's going to be a data entry requirement later.  So if your form has a list of 200 ailments (!) then you may want corresponding codes printed on the form.  There probably are standard codes for recording that, if it corresponds to what you're doing.  ...oh, and people's ailments come and go over time, so you may want to record that someone has diabetes as of March 2018 but did not have it earlier.